# Quotient of $n$-th skeleton by smaller dimensional skeleton

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

Suppose $X$ be a CW complex. Then we know that, $$\frac{X^n}{X^{n-1}}=\underset{\text{$\sigma$ an $n$-cell}}{\large\lor} \Bbb S^n,$$
Where $X^n$ is $n$-th skeleton of $X$ and $X^{n-1}$ is $(n-1)$-th skeleton of $X$ and equality in sense of homeomophism.

My question is is there any well known space to write the quotient $X^n \big/ X^k$, when $1\leq k\leq (n-2)$.

Recently I found a particular case namely, $\Bbb S^{2n+1}\big/\Bbb S^1=\Bbb CP^{n}$ (Homeomophic).

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the statement $S^{2n+1}/S^1 = \mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$. This is not the quotient by the $1$-skeleton, this is the quotient by an $S^1$ action.

Comment: I also just noticed the dimensions don't add up, it should be $S^{2n+1}/S^1 = \mathbb{C}P^{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The space $X^n / X^k$ can be any CW-complex with exactly one $0$-cell and all other cells in dimensions $k+1, \dots, n$.